# A Rolling Quarter

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics

A U.S quarter is rolling on the floor without slipping in such a way that it describes a circular path of radius $R=4 \text{cm}$. The plane of the coin is tilted at an angle of $\theta=45^{∘}$ with respect to the horizontal plane. Find the coin's period $T$ in seconds, that is, the time it takes for the coin to go around the circle of radius $R$. The radius of a U.S quarter is $r=1.2 \text{cm}$.

Comment: I think using $\vec{\tau}=\dot{\vec{L}}$, will solve the problem. Whay have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you drawn a free-body diagram?

Comment: I am writing an answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a well known problem. So, I will try to solve it in the general case. For a somewhat more detailed answer, please look at Chapter 9 of David Morin's  Introduction to Classical Mechanics book. Also, since this looks like a homework, **whenever you think you can do the rest of the problem yourself, stop reading and actually do it yourself!**

[image: picture copied from David Morin's book]

Let's first go to the CM frame. As it can be seen in the figure below, I will illustrate the principal axis by $x_1$(into the page), $x_2$ and $x_3$.

[image: picture copied from David Morin's book]

Let $\Omega$ be the angular velocity of the attaching point of the coin with the floor around the center. This means $T=\frac{2\pi}{\Omega}$.

Using the non-slipping condition, one will find out that the total angular momentum is:

$$\vec{\omega}=\Omega \hat{z}- \frac{R}{r}\Omega \hat{x}_3$$

Now writing $\hat{z}$ in the principal coordinates as $\sin{\theta}\hat{x}_2+\cos{\theta}\hat{x}_3$ we will have:

$$\vec{\omega} = \Omega \sin{\theta} \hat{x}_2 - \Omega \left(\frac{R}{r}-\cos{\theta} \right)\hat{x}_3$$

The principal moments are:

$$I_1=I_2=\frac{mr^2}{4} \ \text{   and   } \; I_3=\frac{mr^2}{2}$$

so the angular momentum will be:

$$\vec{L}= \frac{mr^2}{2}\left(\frac12\Omega \sin{\theta} \hat{x}_2 - \Omega \left(\frac{R}{r}-\cos{\theta} \right)\hat{x}_3\right)$$

Only the horizontal component of $\vec{L}$ is changing:

$$|\frac{d \vec{L}}{dt}|=\Omega L_{\perp}=\frac{1}{4}mr\Omega^2\sin\theta\left( 2R-r\cos\theta \right).$$

Now we have to calculate the torque relative to CM, as well. The torque comes from the forces at the contact point, the horizontal force is $m(R-r\cos\theta)\Omega^2$ and the vertical force will be simply $mg$.

$$|\vec \tau|= mg(r \cos θ) − m(R − r \cos θ)Ω^2 (r \sin θ)$$

Using $|\vec\tau|=|\frac{d\vec L}{dt}|$, we can find:

$$\Omega=2\sqrt{\frac{g}{6 R \tan\theta - 5 r \sin{\theta}}}$$

$$ \Rightarrow T= \pi \sqrt{\frac{6 R \tan\theta - 5 r \sin{\theta}}{g}} \approx 0.446 \text{s}$$